# Database is there but Wordpress cannot establishing a Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am having a server running on my machine and I am calling it over the network. The Server is running fine and there have not been any problems with apache or php yet.

My database is not running on the same machine as apache but in the same local network on a server with the domain "sql.local.network.com".

Now i copied a Wordpress site onto my webserver which has been on another server in the same network, so it should work fine, since the database server is still accessable by both these webservers.

The problem now is, that Wordpress just shows the message `Error establishing a database connection`.

What I did was to access the database with phpmyadmin which I quickly set up on the server. This worked fine, and I was able to access the database.

Also I found a short skript:

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect('sql.local.network.com', 'user', 'password');
  if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo 'Connected successfully';
  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

This echoed `Connected successfully`, which means a simple `mysql_connect` works fine as well.

Also I am able to ping `sql.local.network.com` over my console and get the response `192.168.0.101`.

Everything works, but the Wordpress-page.

Is there a simple solution to fix the Wordpress connection problem I am missing?

Comment: `the same network, so it should work fine` No it shouldn't. Check the mysql `mysql -> users` table, to see, where `user` can connect from. Maybe you need to check your firewall settings too.

Comment: but why is it possible to connect with phpmyadmin from the very same webserver then?

Comment: Ok, then you can access that. And did you set everything in the `wp-config.php` too?

Comment: yes I did, I just changed the adress of the webserver itself obviously, otherwise wp would redirect.

Comment: Then I have no idea.

Comment: Set debugging on in Wordpress and see if you can get more details on the error: http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Just because you can ping the server doesn't mean you have access to it. If the DB server has your IP authorized, the reason I see for this to happen is username and password issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Privileges tab in phpmyadmin and look at the host column. If it's set to "localhost", then that dataabase user can only access the database from the same server as the database. To access remotely, change it to either "%" for any server or to the IP of the server you're trying to connect from.